# How to filter different partition in Dask read_parquet function

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet

I've encountered a problem with loading dask dataframes from parquet file.

Basically I stored my parquet file into categories: aircraft name(AIRCRAFT=name_aircraft), progressive number(a number which identify each mission of the aircraft: PROGRESSIVE=number), year, months and day.

When I try to read the parquet file into a dask dataframe I succeed in filtering the year window and progressive windows but fail in select only some aircrafts.
Here it is reported the function that I use to read  the parquet file

```
ddf = dd.read_parquet(path, engine="pyarrow", index=False, filters=filters)
```

Where path is correctly the path to the file .parquet and filters is a list of tuple with the elements that I want to filter for example:

```
filters = [('PROGRESSIVE', '>=', 0), ('PROGRESSIVE', '<=', 999), ('year', '>', 1999), ('year', '<', 2021), ('AIRCRAFT', '=', 'Aircraft-5')]
```

Now with this kind of filters everything is ok but if I want to select multiple aircraft or, for example, different progressive numbers which are not in the same range window (let's say 753, 800 and 883 only) I cannot load the dataframe properly.

For example if I set

```
filters = [('PROGRESSIVE', '>=', 0), ('PROGRESSIVE', '<=', 999), ('year', '>', 1999), ('year', '<', 2021), ('AIRCRAFT', '=', 'Aircraft-4') ('AIRCRAFT', '=','Aircraft-5')]
```

Then the dataframe loaded is empty in fact: len(ddf_filtered_demo.index) is 0 while selecting only one aircraft is not empty and is correct.

The problem is I can select a range of values (< or >) but cannot select only some elements.

What is the correct way of loading a dask dataframe from a parquet file selecting only some partition not belonging to a unique range of values?

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP's question used `pyarrow`: note that [the Dask documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_parquet.html) on the `filters` kwarg of `dd.read_parquet` says:

"List of filters to apply, like [[('col1', '==', 0), ...], ...]. Using this argument will NOT result in row-wise filtering of the final partitions unless engine="pyarrow-dataset" is also specified. For other engines, filtering is only performed at the partition level, i.e., to prevent the loading of some row-groups and/or files."

In other words, when using a non-pyarrow engine, `filters` cannot pull out specific rows satisfying the filter condition unless the parquet file was created with the right partition key (`partition_on=a` in the case of the answers above).

So while this code works for both `fastparquet` and `pyarrow` engines:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"letter": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "d"], "number": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)
ddf.to_parquet("tmp/partition_on.parquet", engine="fastparquet", partition_on="letter")

# write dummy df to parquet using partition_on kwarg
ddf_1 = dd.read_parquet(
    "tmp/partition/1", engine="fastparquet", filters=[("letter", "==", "a")]
)
```

This code works only for `pyarrow`:

```py
# write dummy df to parquet without partition_on kwarg
ddf.to_parquet("tmp/without_partition_on.parquet", engine="pyarrow")

ddf_2 = dd.read_parquet(
    "tmp/non_partitioned_on.parquet", engine="pyarrow", filters=[("letter", "==", "a"), ("number", ">=", 2)]
)
```

The example above is a MCVE version of the OP's code. That suggests to me that either something is up with your data quality or you should report a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The fastparquet interface supports `in`, so you could do

```
filters = [('PROGRESSIVE', 'in', [753, 80, 883]), ... )
```

I don't know whether arrow supports this syntax, you can try.

The specific non-working example for you sounds like a bug, and you should report it. Ideally, you can recreate it with a minimal example dataset that you create in code.

The following is a simple example which works with current fastparquet main branch (which is what I happen to have installed locally).

```
# make data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': list("abcd")})
df.to_parquet("out.parq", partition_on='a', engine="fastparquet")

# read
pd.read_parquet("out.parq", filters=[('a', 'in', [1, 2, 4])], engine='fastparquet')
```

Comment: with engine = "fastparquet" if i use in as you told me to do an error occours: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Example added, showing this does currently work

Comment: @AndreaLeggio I had to exchange the selector list with a tuple to get it working. `[1, 2, 4]` --> `(1, 2, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the example from mdurant to be specific to dask would be:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

# make data
df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': list("abcd")}), npartitions=1)
df.to_parquet("out.parq", partition_on='a', engine="fastparquet") 

# read
dd.read_parquet("out.parq", filters=[('a', 'in', (1, 2, 4))], engine='fastparquet').compute()
```

It looks like dask performs a flattening of the filters ([link](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/4299f6d026878c324089ca84ef7ea4cfc68aa6a7/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/utils.py#L490)) and so you'll get a type error if you have a list in your filter (which happens when the `_flatten_filter()` function attempts to build a set). But, if you provide the values as a tuple rather than a list the filter works properly.